# Implement JWT Firebase in php backend?

Tags: php, firebase, jwt

I have an Android App that corresponds with a php backend. I want to use Firebase JWT. Creating the JWT in the Android App seems to work fine, but I can't get the php script to recognize this command:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';  
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;         // The syntax error is marked here 


$payload = array(
    "user_id" => 123456,
    "user_name" => "john.doe",
    "exp" => time() + 3600 
);

$secretKey = 'my_secret_key';
$algorithm = 'HS256';

$token = JWT::encode($payload, $secretKey, $algorithm);


require_once 'some other script';
....
```

It gives me a syntax error (-> syntax error, unexpected 'Firebase', expecting '(') and I can't figure out why.

What I've done:

- Installed composer
- Ran "composer require firebase/php-jwt" in my projects root folder
- Installed paragonie, as I have php 5.6.40
- vendor folder (incl. autoload.php), composer.json and composer.lock are all there, so I want to assume that the library was installed correctly?

EDIT:
I upgraded my version of PHP to 7.4.26 now, thinking this might be the problem. Still the same error occurs.

I am sure my mistake is something simple I overlook - but can anyone please point me to it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that is the line that is giving the error? Have you tried writing a file with just that line, it just those first two lines? Because I can't see any problem with that line.

Comment: @IMSoP - thank you for this hint, I just tried it in a separate file (with nothing in it but those two lines) and I get the same error.

Comment: you are probably using `use` in wrong place, we need the whole source of that file (or at least what's on top of it)